# 'useSplashScreen' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 2.5 getting this warning in Xcode

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5

I have Installed Cordova 2.5 and Was trying Hello World in project in Xcode and got this warning. Does any1 have any idea how to solve this warning..
Thanks

Comment: Stop using `useSplashScreen` and perhaps use an alternative if one is available.  I expect the documentation can provide more information.  Read it.

Comment: Ya in the doc it says that stop using Deprecated methods but I thought some1 might have better solution.

Comment: see http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/hiding-and-showing-the-ios-status-bar-in-phonegap-2-5-0/#more-77

Answer (score 5):

You can comment out the line in AppDelegate.m (line 68 according to 2.5.0)

```
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
```

This should remove the warning on your next build.

Answer (score 2):

Splash screen control has now been split out into the Splashscreen plugin:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

(There's a full example of its use on that page)

Comment: If this is deprecated then why is the new version shipping this way? Open terminal and create a new project in xcode, when you try to run it you will get this warning. This is plain vanilla, straight from the phonegap package with no changes. Perplexed.

Comment: @timbad2021 I suspect no-one has updated the template app yet!

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this issue, the only thing you have to do is comment the line in the AppDelegate.m, save the file and run the application again.

This was left uncommented for backward compatibilities.

The template comes already with the plugin included, you can check it in the plugins section of the config.xml file.

You can review more information on http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen as rmc47 pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can comment out this line of code in your project's AppDelegate.m file (which I generally don't recommend), you could also just suppress the warning using the following #pragma directives:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    /* ... code generating warning/deprecation message ... */
    return YES;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```